# Managing Tab Indexes for Links in Stacks and Groups using FLuentUI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have a list of items. I noticed that when rendered using Stacks and groups, the tabindex of the link element is set to 0, while the tabindex of the rest of the link elements is set to -1. Is there a way to set all tab indexes to 0?

This is the link of my demo code https://jsfiddle.net/yrag1fkj/8/

**Note** that this is done dynamically, so explicitly setting the `tabIndex={0}` does not work for me

[image: Demo]